# How to generate jacobian of a tensor-valued function using torch.autograd?

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd, automatic-differentiation

Computing the jacobian of a function f : R^d -> R^d is not too hard:

```
def jacobian(y, x):
    k, d = x.shape
    jacobian = list()
    
    for i in range(d):
        v = torch.zeros_like(y)
        v[:, i] = 1.
        dy_dx = torch.autograd.grad(y, x, grad_outputs = v, retain_graph = True, create_graph = True, allow_unused = True)[0]  # shape [k, d]
        jacobian.append(dy_dx)
    jacobian = torch.stack(jacobian, dim = 1).requires_grad_()
    return jacobian
```

Above, `jacobian` is invoked with `y = f(x)`. However, now I have a function `g = g(t, x)`, where `t` is a `torch.tensor` of shape `k` and `x` is a `torch.tensor` of shape `(k, d1, d2, d3)`. The result of `g` is again a `torch.tensor` of shape `(k, d1, d2, d3)`

I've tried to use my already existing `jacobian` function. What I did was

```
y = g(t, x)
x = x.flatten(1)
y = y.flatten(1)
jacobian(y, x)
```

The problem is that all the time `dy_dx` is `None`. The only explanation I have for this is that most probably the dependency graph is broken after the `flatten(1)` call.

So, what can I do here? I should remark that what I actually want to compute is the divergence. That is, the trace of the jacobian. If there is a more performant solution for that specific case available, I'd be interested in that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you are passing `x.flatten(1)` as an input even though `y` - let alone `y.flatten(1)` - was computed from `x`, not `x.flatten(1)`. Instead, you could avoid the flattening with something like this:

```
def jacobian(y, x):
    jacobian = []
    for i in range(x.numel()//len(x)):
        v = torch.zeros_like(y.flatten(1))
        v[:, i] = 1.
        dy_dx, *_ = torch.autograd.grad(y, x, v.view_as(x), 
                      retain_graph=True, create_graph=True, allow_unused=True)
        jacobian.append(dy_dx)
    jacobian = torch.stack(jacobian, dim=1)
    return jacobian
```

So after calling the function, you can flatten `d1`, `d2`, and `d3` together. Here is a minimal example:

```
x = torch.rand(1,3,2,2, requires_grad=True)
J = jacobian(x**2, x)

> J.flatten(-3)
tensor([[[1.2363, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.2386, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0451, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.4160, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.4090, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.7642, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3041, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.1995]]],
       grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>)
```

From here, I guess you can compute the trace you're looking for with [`torch.trace`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.trace.html).

```
> [j.trace() for j in J.flatten(-3)]
[tensor(7.6128, grad_fn=<TraceBackward0>)]
```

Keep in mind you can also use the builtin [`jacobian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.jacobian.html#torch.autograd.functional.jacobian) function:

```
J = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(lambda x: g(t, x), x)
```

However, you will need to reshape the result:

```
k = x.numel()//len(x)

> [j.trace() for j in J.view(len(x), k, k)]
[tensor(7.6128)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I actually have a strong C++ background and need to work on a Python projection for the first time. Some of the notation is new to me, but I guess `[j.trace() for j in J.flatten(-3)]` is a list with `x.shape[0]` entries? Why is it a single tensor in your output (if that's what your claiming with `[tensor(7.6128, grad_fn=<TraceBackward0>)]`)? On what would I call `torch.trace` here?

Comment: Regarding `torch.autograd.functional.jacobian`: My actual `g` is a score model. It appears that `torch.autograd.functional.jacobian` is terribly slow on that.

Comment: You are correct `[j.trace() for j in J.flatten(-3)]` is a list comprehension which iterates through the `x.shape[0]` matrices and computes the trace. I assumed that would be the quantity you are looking for, but do you have an example or the actual mathematical expression for it?

Comment: The actual mathematical expression $\nabla\cdot f$, where $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: Do you have a reference page to share where I can find the definition of such operator?